# Add a dictionary of data model in the completion: escaping

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsurlsession

I have a data model for the data that I get from the server

it's part of it (since it's very long I just copy a part of it)

```
public struct ExportUserDataModel: Decodable {

   public let username: String
   public let id: Int
   public let data: [Int]

...
```

Then, we use a custom form of `NSURLSeasson`to fetch Data

```
 public func fetchtExportCSV(id: Int, completion: @escaping Result<[ExportUserDataModel]>.Completion) {
      let request = userRequest.export(id: id)
       requestProvider.execute([ExportUserDataModel].self, request: request, on: .main) { result in
          switch result {
          case .success(let object):
             completion(.success(object))
          case .error(let error):
             logger.error(.response, error)
             completion(.error(error))
          }
       }
    }
```

Here, if the data comes in an array it works erectly fine. but know, data come in a dictionary 
something like that

```
{
  "username" : "Dubbeloo",
  "id" : 12869,
  "data" : [
    [
      1904
    ],
    [
      1928
    ]
}
```

my problem is, how can I use add the data in the fetch function to get the dictionary, now it's array `[ExportUserDataModel]` and `[ExportUserDataModel].self`

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: add implementation for `requestProvider.execute`  it's where you should do edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
requestProvider.execute([ExportUserDataModel].self, request: request, on: .main) { result in
```

to

```
requestProvider.execute(ExportUserDataModel.self, request: request, on: .main) { result in
```

If you need to support both , check the data cast result or

```
do {
      // decode an array 
   }
    catch {
       // decode a dictionary 
    }
```

Comment: change to `Result<ExportUserDataModel>`